# The requirments.txt file on Github repo unable to install the python packages

Tags: python, github, pip

I downloaded a repository from the Github and save it to the computer's download(not clone) folder. In the description section of the repository it is written that their project's dependency is defined in the requirments.txt file and one can install the packages using **"pip3 install -r requirments.txt"**. So I navigate to the folder in my local computer where requirments.txt exists, and run the command.

I received the error **ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirments.txt'**

However, I checked the folder using ls command. Requirments.txt file within the folder. I am not sure why pip3 unable to find requirments.txt within the folder.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS as operating system.

Comment: Are you sure it's `requirments.txt` and not `requirements.txt` (missed `e` in the middle)? Can we see the copy/pasted text output from you `ls` command?

Comment: What's the actual file name? `Requirments.txt`, `requirments.txt`, `Requirements.txt`,  or `requirements.txt`?

Comment: The command is "pip3 install -r requirments.txt". The error is "ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirments.txt'". The file name is requirments.txt

Answer (score 2):

```
  pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Try running this.
The file name might be 'requirements.txt'.

Comment: I tried but did not work

Answer (score -1):

I solved it. The correct command should be "pip3 install -r requirements.txt
".